# Creating a php date object current date without seconds

Tags: php

I need a date object that has a time of 12:00:00am for the current day (meaning no seconds). I am converting that to that to the number of seconds and passing it in another function. It is eventually used for a report filter using date = "someDateHere' off the database, and the hanging seconds in the field are screwing up the report.

I'm not sure what to put in the second parameter in the time function  - leaving it blank will use the current time, which is what I do not want. I can't find examples or anything in the php doc.  If there is another function that will do the job, I am open to suggestions. This should be simple, but it is alluding me.

```
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Detroit');
        $now = date("Y-m-d 0:0:0");
        echo $now . '<br/>';
        $now = time($now,0);
        echo $now . '<br/>';
```

Thanks in advance.

edit: Please note: I need to convert that date object to seconds. That is where the timestamp is screwing me up with strtotime function and time function. Even though I am passing it a dateobject *without* a timestamp, converting it into seconds not-so-conveniently is inserting the timestamp as the second parameter which defaults to the current time.

Comment: time() takes no arguments. what you're doing is pointless. why not just `strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))` to get the unix timestamp for midnight?

Comment: strtotime adds a timestamp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are lots of available options here, since PHP accepts a wide variety of time formats.

```
$midnight = strtotime('midnight');
$midnight = strtotime('today');
$midnight = strtotime('12:00am');
$midnight = strtotime('00:00');
// etc.
```

Or in [DateTime](http://php.net/class.datetime) form:

```
$midnight = new DateTime('midnight');
$midnight = new DateTime('today');
$midnight = new DateTime('12:00am');
$midnight = new DateTime('00:00');
// etc.
```

See [time formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats.time) and [relative formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative) in the manual for a complete list of formats with descriptions.

Comment: But how do I get it to seconds since January 1 1970 without involving the timestamp?

Comment: Huh? For the `strtotime()` examples, `$midnight` is the timestamp which is the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970. For the `DateTime` examples, use [`getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/datetime.gettimestamp) (or [`format('U')`](http://php.net/datetime.format) on older PHPs).

Comment: Ultimately this answer and subsequent comment got me where I needed to go. I learned more about dealing with the timestamp and the DateTime object than the php docs, so while other current answers also work (thank you!), I am marking this as correct.

Comment: @Cymbals, I work on the PHP documentation. I would appreciate it if you could send me a few words (my email is my username here @php.net) on any faults or improvements we could make for the DateTime pages. SO is great for Q&A but it would be nice to make the manual the best it can be.

Comment: Wow, Salathe, thanks. There are no faults - I just didn't realize you could do a date/time object like this, and then not have to worry about the timestamp as a result. The docs are very thorough - and I love php.net - it sets the example for others. Sometimes understanding them via an example like yours and applying it to a situation like this or dates of birth would be helpful to others, if I missed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I'd stop using those functions entirely, and start taking advantage of the DateTime class!

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/Detroit"));
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: But how do I get it to seconds since January 1 1970 without involving the timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

time() takes no arguments. what you're doing is pointless. why not just `strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))` to get the unix timestamp for midnight?

Comment: strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )  is including the timestamp

Comment: it's supposed to. php's internal time format is a unix time stamp: seconds since jan 1/1970 utc. you cannot get away from this. all you can do is ensure that the timestamp you have represents midnight of the day you want, which means yyyy-mm-hh 00:00:00.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the second half of that comment. I am upvoting this response.

Answer (score 0):

i think mktime() is just what you need http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

```
<?php
// Set the default timezone to use. Available as of PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Prints: July 1, 2000 is on a Saturday
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));

// Prints something like: 2006-04-05T01:02:03+00:00
echo date('c', mktime(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2006));
?>
```

Comment: mktime requires that I know what day it is. I need the current day.

Comment: if you would read the documentation witch i linked to you would see that Arguments may be left out in order from right to left; any arguments thus omitted will be set to the current value according to the local date and time.

Comment: Ah, ok- so I could leave out the date and set the time to midnight. Didn't see/know that. Cool. Thank you! :)